# Error : error C2663: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am getting above error , if anybody have any idea please help me.

I am getting this error in `void traverse` function where i have used `insert` function for inserting into map.

```
struct node {
    int weight;
    unsigned char value;
    const node *child0;
    const node *child1;
    map<unsigned char, string> huffmanTable;

    node( unsigned char c = 0, int i = -1 ) {
        value = c;
        weight = i;
        child0 = 0;
        child1 = 0;
    }

    node( const node* c0, const node *c1 ) {
        value = 0;
        weight = c0->weight + c1->weight;
        child0 = c0;
        child1 = c1;
    }

    bool operator<( const node &a ) const {
        return weight >a.weight;
    }

    void traverse(ostream& o,string code="") const {

    if ( child0 ) {
        child0->traverse(o, code + '0' );
        child1->traverse(o, code + '1' );
    } else {
        o<<value<<"\t";
        cout <<" " <<value <<"    ";

        o<<weight<<"\t";
        cout <<weight;
        o<<code<<endl;

        cout <<"     " <<code <<endl;
        huffmanTable.insert(pair<unsigned char, std::string>(value,code));

    }
}

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to add to the map **huffmanTable** from a const function. A const member function is not allowed to modify the **this** object. Your options are

1. You can make the map mutable

   mutable map  huffmanTable;

or

1. Remove the const from traverse function

   void traverse(ostream& o,string code=""){

Comment: you saved my lot of time. Thanks

Comment: @Rajul I hope you didn't make the variable `mutable`. I'm inclined to downvote this answer just for suggesting that.

Comment: @Luchian I have removed const from function

Comment: @LuchianGrigore what is wrong with giving all the options to OP. A function called `traverse` that is mutating the object is equally bad IMHO